# Java script function from head cause not defined ReferenceError in body

Tags: javascript, cookies

This question has been asked a lot times in the SO. I read through many of these answers, but could not find right solution. The problem is that js is defined in a separate file, which is load in the `head` section of the page, but when a function from this file is invoke, js prompts with ReferenceError. The most bizarre thing is that different function from the file works in the other page.
How head looks like:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="mysecrettokenissecret">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webpage.local:8000/css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webpage.local:8000/css/additional.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://webpage.local:8000/js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://webpage.local:8000/js/additional.js"></script>
</head>
```

File with problem:

```
function op_check(an_array)
{
    var score = 0;
    for(i=0; i<an_array.length; i++)
    {
        if(an_array[i] != null)
        { score++; }
    }
    if(score > 0)
    { return true; } 
    else
    { return false; }
}

function setCookie(cookie_name, cookie_value, expiration_interval)
{
    var date = new Date()
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expiration_interval*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cookie_name + "=" + cookie_value + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cookie_name)
{
    var name = cookie_name + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++)
    {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
        { c = c.substring(1); }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0)
        { return c.substring(name.length, c.length); }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie(cookie_name)
{
    var cookie_value = getCookie(cookie_name);
    if (cookie_value == "")
    { return false; }
    else if(cookie_value == "true")
    { return true; } 
    else
    { return "Something went wrong."; }
}

function agree_button_click()
{
    setCookie("cookie_law", true, 365);
}
```

Script in `body` which should invoke the `checkCookie` function.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var cookie_law_exists = checkCookie("cookie_law");
        var cookie_law_value = getCookie("cookie_law")

        if(cookie_law_exists == false || cookie_law_value == false)
        {
            $('#cookieRODOModal').modal('show')
        }
        else
        {
            $('#cookieRODOModal').modal('hide')
        }
        function change_example_url()
        {
            var urls = [
                'not important 1',
                'not important 2'
            ]
            var max = urls.length;
            var roll =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1));
            $("#example_url").text(urls[roll]);
        }
        var new_url;
        new_url = setInterval(change_example_url, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

Thank you for your help.

Edit - Error message:

```
app.js:1 jQuery.Deferred exception: checkCookie is not defined 
ReferenceError: checkCookie is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://webpage.local:8000/:38:37)
at c (http://webpage.local:8000/js/app.js:1:52675)
at l (http://webpage.local:8000/js/app.js:1:52977) undefined
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Comment: Ok, error message added.

Comment: Error occurs in line 1 of `app.js`, what do you run in this file?

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to reload cache in the broweser.